# Get sObject Gender via API

Tags: apex, describesobject

Is there any way I could get the Gender of a CustomObject?

I thought it would be something like

```
tcana__Tipo_Veiculo__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getGender()
```

But it didn't work

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this information is available on [CustomObjectTranslation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm). Specifically, it has a `gender` field.

You can find the same information at the field level using [CustomFieldTranslation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm#customFieldTranslation).